What are the issues when not using @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")?
In my Board entity, there is a field.
private String content;

And, if i run the following query on my database(mysql),
ALTER TABLE board MODIFY content TEXT;

Will there be any issues du to the mismatch between the two?
In my test, it seems like there are no problems.
Do I not need to add @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT") to the content field?
I’m wondering if there might be any issues I’m not aware of. Thanks

Of note, TEXT is over 65,000 characters of data possible, so it might be better to use Varchar (#) with # being the max amount of characters that will be stored.  Or in other words, Not exactly efficient, yet it  could technically function.  If you have strings that are tens of thousands of characters, ok text might be okay, but if you are storing strings less than 128 to 256 characters .. you might consider using varchar if you would want to have faster database pulls.  Or in other words, if you don't do this, the database will be much larger than it needs to be, so data pulls will be slowed.

There should be no issues if your tests are passing and Hibernate is handling the mapping correctly. Adding @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT") is not strictly necessary unless you want to explicitly declare the column type for clarity or control over the schema.

Actually you do need to define the column type otherwise it won't know what type of data goes into that column.
